# Merging JSON files using a bash script

Tags: json, bash, awk

I am very new to bash scripting. I attempted to write a script that merges several json files. For example:

File 1:

```
{
  "file1": {
     "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

File 2:

```
{
  "file1": {
     "lorem": "ipsum"
  }
}
```

Merged File:

```
{
  "file1": {
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  "file2": {
    "lorem": "ipsum"
  }
}
```

This is what I came up with:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "{"} FNR > 1 && last_file == FILENAME {print line} FNR == 1 {line = ""} FNR==1 && FNR != NR {printf ","} FNR > 1 {line = $0} {last_file = FILENAME} END{print "}"}' json_files/* > json_files/all_merged.json
```

It works but I feel there is a better way of doing this. Any ideas?

Comment: I assume the key for file 2 should be `"file2"` ?

Comment: Indeed. Missed that! Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Handling JSON with awk is not a terribly good idea. Arbitrary changes in meaningless whitespace will break your code. Instead, use [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/); it is made for this sort of thing. To combine two objects, use the `*` operator, i.e., for two files:

```
jq -s '.[0] * .[1]' file1.json file2.json
```

And for arbitrarily many files, use `reduce` to apply it sequentially to all:

```
jq -s 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)' json_files/*
```

The `-s` switch makes `jq` read the contents of the JSON files into a large array before handling them.

Comment: That'll probably work as well in this case. There's a difference if objects in two files have an attribute of the same name, in which case `*` will merge the two attributes (if they're both objects/arrays) while `+` will pick the one that appears last. The example data suggests that collisions shouldn't happen, and in that case both yield the same result.

Comment: Thank you guys! I did not know about jq.

Comment: This doesn't appear to merge arrays as I had hoped. If both files have an array of the same name, the out ends up with the the elements of the from the array in the last file

Comment: You can merge a literal piece of JSON with: `jq '. * $p' file.json --argjson p '{"foo": "bar"}'`

Comment: Does this solution deep merges objects with same name or only shallow merge is performed?