# Is there a way to merge multiple json files without opening them?

Tags: python, json, merge

I have a large number of big `json` files and I cannot open all of them at the same time. I'm trying to merge them into one `json` file, but all the solutions I find on SO (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57422734/how-to-merge-multiple-json-files-into-one-file-in-python)) require opening the files which causes my machine to crash. I was wondering if there's a way to merge them without opening them

Comment: You are having troubles working with large JSON files and now you want to solve that by creating an even larger one?

Comment: Haha yea that might sound a bit silly. But, I need to upload one file as a dataset somewhere, hence the question

Comment: Hope this will work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636331/merging-json-files-using-a-bash-script