# Merge multiple compile_command.json files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clangd

Is there any lightweight method or VsCode extension to merge all `compile_command.json` files in different build folders in the whole workspace? If possible, I think it would be a convenient way for `Clangd` to configure intellisense.

**Update**:

Here is a hypothetical workspace

```
├── build
│   └── compile_command.json
├── compile_command.json
└── src
    ├── project_A
    │   └── build
    │       └── compile_command.json
    └── project_B
        └── build
            └── compile_command.json
```

, and usually workspaces aren't constructed in such a chaotic way. I want to merge all `compile_command.json` files, no matter the hierarchy, and output the combined file at the top directory in a simple way.

Comment: hi, i'm currently having the same problem. There is a linux command called `jc`. the usage looks like this:
```
COMPILE_DATABASES=$(find $source_code/samples -name "compile_commands.json" -printf "%p ")
jq -s 'add' $COMPILE_DATABASES > $SONAR_QUBE_HOME/compile_commands.json
```

But i am searching a solution for windows.
Regards

Comment: @Dario.Casciato You can get `jq` on Windows too.

Comment: You just want to append one file to the end of another file? It's just `file1 >> file2`. Did you try that? Or any other method? Or you need to logically parse each json and then create one big json? That also is not a big deal.

Comment: @pptaszni I assume it needs to be a valid JSON for Clangd to understand it. Each file is a big `[...]` list, and they need to be merged together.

Comment: @pptaszni I have tried the method you mentioned. If there are lots of `.json` files, it would be a lot of repeated work. I want to automatically locate all `build` folders and combine all `.json` files. Even though the `build` folders may be in different sub-directories.

Comment: @Dario.Casciato Hi! Thanks for your comment. I need to dive deeper into this command, and a detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Then I think the question has to be a bit focused. What you need is: "how to locate all build folders", "how to find all files with specific name", "how to parse json", "how to combine multiple jsons into one big json". Each of those small tasks is easy, and the solutions are provided here in SO. Then all of them have to be integrated together. For merging jsons (I think that's the biggest issue), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29636525/4165552). In case you need it on windows: https://jqlang.github.io/jq/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge multiple json files in a directory with jq or any tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63046989/11107541)

Comment: @starball Thanks for your help. But I'd like to locate all `JSON` files automatically on different paths. I have updated my question to describe my idea more clearly.

Comment: it's not that difficult to modify what you see in that answer. as long as your shell supports it, just change the `*.json` to `**/*.json`.

Comment: @starball Thanks a lot. I have spent some time understanding this command and successfully achieved the combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72205326/19644538) and the comment by @starball,

```
jq -s add **/*.json > merged.json
```

can search all `.json` files in the current and below paths and combine the output to `merged.json`, where

`-s`: The entire input is passed to the filter as a single long string;

`add`: The filter `add` takes as input an array, and produces as output the elements of the array added together;

`**/*.json`: The pattern `**/*.json` will therefore expand to the pathname of any file that has a filename suffix of `.json` anywhere in or below the current directory.

Finally, this command can be configured as a task for convenience in VsCode with

```
{
    "label": "Combine compile_commands.json",
    "type": "shell",
    "command":"jq -s add **/*.json > compile_commands.json",
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
}
```

References:

1. https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#invoking-jq
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457404